# How to use href to link css file path starting from root?

Tags: html, css, path

I would like to link to a style file, giving absolute path:

*/var/www/html/2/default/a.html*:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="/var/www/html/2/default/style.css" rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

However, the html is not using that style. Why it cannot find that file with absolute path?

Comment: html parser can not find your css with the abolute path.

Comment: try using http://yourdomain.com/2/default/style.css where "http://yourdomain.com" is obviously your domain.

Comment: @MaximJin The question is *why*.